# create a string of variable length in python

Tags: python

i need to create a string consisting of spaces, and the length of the string needs to be determined at runtime.

here is what i am doing:

```
suffix = "".join([' ' for x in range(0, max)])
```

There must be a **better** way, a more **clever** way, and an **easier** way. what are the ways?

**edit:** well this is simpler then i imagined. there is only the 1 way and it all of the above, heh :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `max` for a variable name.

```
suffix = ' ' * nb_spaces
```

Comment: ha, i was wondering why there wasnt a ruby .times() operator. it was hiding there all along

Comment: Because `max` is the name of a built-in function. And Python will cheerfully let you shadow that function, and you won't notice it until you go to use the `max` function and get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [string "multiplication."](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings#Numerical)

```
suffix = " " * numSpaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [string multiplication.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings#Numerical)

```
>>> print "x" * 5
xxxxx
```